# Dividing dictionary that contain lists in python

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I am new in programming and in python and I am trying to create a model using this language.
In my model, I will create a community that is a group of households. Each community will be a list containing all the households and each household will be a dictionary containing the list of male, females, the number of members etc (therefore will include int and list). So would be something like:

```
hh = {'num_members' : 0, #number members hshd
      'list_male' : [] #list male members
      'list_female' : [] #list female members}
```

In each members list, there will be the age of each individual living in the household, so, for example, imagine a household have 4 females and 3 males, the list_female would be something like list_female = [4,15,50,40], the list_male = [45,30,13] and the num_members = 7
The list will be created randomly and updated during the model (people will have kids, die etc).

What I want to do is: if the number of members (num_members) exceed the max household size I will divide the household into two households, each containing half of the members of the lists (define randomly), but I have no idea how to do so. I saw some ways to divide dictionary but none contained a list involved so I am a bit lost. Any idea how I could do so?

One point that is important to remember is that when I create the new household it will be included in the community (and each household will be accessed in a loop, for the whole community)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a lot of requirements listed here, and very little effort shown.  Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comments. I am sorry if appeared I did little effort on trying to sort it out, that is not what happened. I've researching in the internet for a quite long time,  tried to use the append but I couldn't sort it out how to access one list while considering in another and that is why I didn't show my attempts. I am having difficulty with python logics and got stuck trying to know how to start things and that is why I decide to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into pieces, and they're all easy:

> if the number of members (num_members) exceed the max household size

```
if hh['num_members'] > max_household_size:
```

> I will divide the household into two households

```
    hh1, hh2 = {}, {}
```

> each containing half of the members of the lists (define randomly)

OK, let's write a function to help with this:

```
def split_list(lst):
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    for member in lst:
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            lst1.append(member)
        else:
            lst2.append(member)
    return lst1, lst2
```

And now, we can just call that function once for males, once for females, and gather all the results back up into two new dicts:

```
    hh1['list_female'], hh2['list_female'] = split(hh['list_female'])
    hh1['list_male'], hh2['list_male'] = split(hh['list_male'])
    hh1['num_members'] = len(hh1['list_male']) + len(hh1['list_female'])
    hh2['num_members'] = len(hh2['list_male']) + len(hh2['list_female'])
```

There are ways you can make this more terse, or more clever, but start with code you can definitely understand, and then see if you can improve it from there without confusing yourself; don't try to write the cleverest thing first.

Of course you still need to figure out what to *do* with this `hh1` and `hh2`, and I'm sure there are other parts of your problem that aren't trivial, but this should be enough to get you unstuck.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! It does help me to understand who to start. What I am in doubt if, using this split_list ain't I only splitting the list, but not annexing it to a new dictionary. I tried to put in the code the inclusion of a new household, but I am not sure if it makes sense. I will write in the next comment what I thought cause it do not fit here

Comment: @PrisCunha Yes, `split_list` just returns two new lists. Which is why the code right below it stores those lists into the appropriate place in the new dicts.

Comment: if hh['num_members'] > max_hh_side:
       hh2 = comunnity.append(hh)
       for member in hh['list_male']:
           if uniform(0,1) < 0.5:
               hh['list_male'].append(member)
           else:
               hh2['list_male'].append(member)
       for member in hh['list_female']:
           if uniform(0,1) < 0.5:
               hh['list_female'].append(member)
           else:
               hh2['list_female'].append(member)

Answer (score 0):

You can set conditional statements depending on what you want you max household size to be, and depending on how many males and females you want in a maximum list. Below I have an example for males. Lists have a method called .pop() and another method called .append() which we can use in this example. .pop() can remove a specified element from a list based on its' index location. .append() can add an element to the end of an empty list. If the maximum household size is exceeded we can pop a specified number of values from the first list. We can also use the range function to select the range of people that we want to pop() from the list in order to divide the list in half, assuming that the number of people within the list is an even number. If it is an odd number, we can add 1.

```
hh = {'num_members': 10,
     'list_male': [30, 29, 17, 10, 15, 22, 19],
     'list_female': [40, 70, 22],
     }

if hh['num_members'] >= 10:
      hh['list_male2'] = []
      hh['list_female2'] = []
      number = len(hh['list_male'])
      number_female = len(hh['list_female'])

      if number % 2 == 0:
          divide_num = number / 2
          divide_num = int(divide_num)
          for person in range(0, divide_num + 1):
             person = hh['list_male'].pop()
             hh['list_male2'].append(person)

      if number_female % 2 == 0:
          divide_num_female = number_female / 2
          divide_num_female = int(divide_num_female)
          for person in range(0, divide_num_female + 1):
              person = hh['list_female'].pop()
              hh['list_female2'].append(person)

      if number % 2 != 0: 
          number = number + 1
          divide_num = number / 2
          divide_num = int(divide_num)
          for i in range(divide_num):
              person = hh['list_male'].pop()
              hh['list_male2'].append(person)

      if number_female % 2 != 0:
          number_female = number_female + 1
          divide_num_female = number_female / 2
          divide_num_female = int(divide_num_female)
          for i in range(divide_num_female):
             person = hh['list_female'].pop()
             hh['list_female2'].append(person)


print(hh)
```

The above code will give you the following output and split the list in half (based on the fact that we have an uneven amount of people in both lists we split the lists based on that uneven number):

```
{'num_members': 10, 'list_male': [30, 29, 17], 'list_female': [40], 'list_male2': [19, 22, 15, 10], 'list_female2': [22, 70]}
```

As you can see, we have added additional lists to the dictionary to split members into two separate households based on the condition that the number of members exceeds the maximum limit.